# Test a Coprocessor within HBaseTestingUtility

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hbasetestingutility

I've made an HBase Endpoint Coprocessor, closely based on the example given [here](https://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/hbase-coprocessors). I'd like to test it using the HBaseTestingUtility, but no suggestions for loading Coprocessors seem like they will work in this setup.

I start the cluster via:

```
HBaseTestingUtility hbaseUtility = new HBaseTestingUtility();
hbaseUtility.startMiniCluster();
hbaseUtility.createTable(TableName.valueOf("test"), "a");
```

Deployment suggestions online include:

1. Placing the Coprocessor jar on the HDFS and using HBase shell.
2. Adding a property to `hbase-site.xml`, placing the Coprocessor jar in the HBase lib dir, and restarting HBase.
3. Placing the Coprocessor jar on the HDFS and using `hTableDescriptor.addCoprocessor(...)`.

`3.` sounds like the only remotely feasible option, but I'd have to have the Coprocessor jar in a known location, and would have to set up a local HDFS cluster. I'd much prefer to be able to pull in the Coprocessor jar from my local Maven repo and deploy it from a local location.

Can anyone recommend the best way to test a Coprocessor using the HBaseTestingUtility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HTableDescriptor` has an [`addCoprocessor(String class)` method](https://hbase.apache.org/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HTableDescriptor.html#addCoprocessor(java.lang.String)), which will find the Coprocessor on the classpath. My test class now looks like:

```
HBaseTestingUtility hbaseUtility = new HBaseTestingUtility();
hbaseUtility.startMiniCluster();
TableName table = TableName.valueOf("test");
hbaseUtility.createTable(table , "a");
hBaseAdmin.disableTable(table);
HTableDescriptor hTableDescriptor = new HTableDescriptor(table);
hTableDescriptor.addCoprocessor("uk.co.hadoopathome.hbase.coprocessor.SumEndpoint");
HColumnDescriptor colFam = new HColumnDescriptor("a");
hTableDescriptor.addFamily(colFam);
hBaseAdmin.modifyTable(table, hTableDescriptor);
hBaseAdmin.enableTable(table);
```

where the `SumEndpoint` class is the class that implements `Coprocessor`.